# Google OAuth credentials - For different scopes

Tags: node.js, google-api-webmasters

I am trying to get client authorization for my app to access Google Search Console API. OAuth credentials are used for this authorization.

But one OAuth credential set has been already used for login purpose.

If Search console API scopes are added to my project in OAuth consent screen, will it request for authorization from the user for search console during login?

The goal is to keep the authorization process for login and google search console as separate entity. Can this be achieved?

Will incremental authorization help?